# Spark Streaming:how to sum up all result for several DStreams?

Tags: spark-streaming, rdd, dstream

I am now using Spark Streaming + Kafka to construct my message processing system.But I have a little technical problem , I will describe it below:

For example , I want to do a wordcount for each **10 minutes**,So, in my earliest code,I set Batch Interval to 10 minutes.Code is like below:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(args(0)).setMaster(args(1))
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(10))
```

But I don't think it is a very good solution because 10 minutes is what a long time and large amount of data that my memory cannot sustain so much data.So , I want to reduce batch interval to 1 minutes, like:

```
 val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName(args(0)).setMaster(args(1))
 val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(1))
```

Then the problem comes:How can I sum up the result of 10 minutes for ten '1 minutes'? I think this word can only be done in **driver** instead of **worker** program,what can I do?

I am new learner of Spark Streaming.Any one can give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have my idea. In this condition ,I should use **stateful function** like `UpdateStateByKey()` because , since what I want is a global 10 minutes' result but what I can get is just each intermediate result of each 1 minute , so before each 10 minutes end , I have to record the state of each 1 minute , such as the word count result of each 1 minute and add them up for each 1 minute.

Answer (score 0):

Posting here as I had a similar issue and came across the [Window Operations](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations) section of Spark Streaming. In the poster's original case, they want a count for the past 10 minutes, done every 10 minutes although their program calculates counts each 1 minute. Assuming we have `counts` defined and calculated as the standard word count (i.e. at a 1-minute batch duration, with tuples (word, count)), we could follow the linked guide and define something along the lines of

```
// Reduce/count last 10 seconds worth of data, every 10 seconds
val windowedWordCounts = counts.reduceByKeyAndWindow(_+_, Seconds(10), Seconds(10))
```

where `_+_` is a sum function.